# IBatis.net converting project from VS2003 to VS2008 crashes on load

Tags: c#, ibatis.net

The project has been working fine in 2003 but when opening it in 2008 we now get the below error.  I've tried ripping all of the code out of the 'Accessory' result map and then it just goes onto the next result map and tells me the same error with that one.  Any thoughts?

[ERROR]-- Accessing Accessory Datasource --
Error: Data connection configurations are invalid.

Descriptive: Net.Autodata.Accessories.Exceptions.AccessoryConnectException: Failed loading iBATIS.NET Default SQL MAP ---> IBatisNet.Common.Exceptions.ConfigurationException: 
- The error occurred while loading SqlMap.
- initialize ResultMap
- The error occurred in .
- Check the Accessories.Accessory. ---> IBatisNet.Common.Exceptions.ConfigurationException: Could not configure ResultMap named "Accessories.Accessory", Cause: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at IBatisNet.Common.Utilities.Objects.ObjectFactory.CreateFactory(Type typeToCreate, Type[] types)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.ResultMapping.ResultMap.GetChildNode(ConfigurationScope configScope)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.ResultMapping.ResultMap.Initialize(ConfigurationScope configScope)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.ResultMapping.ResultMap.Initialize(ConfigurationScope configScope)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.Serializers.ResultMapDeSerializer.Deserialize(XmlNode node, ConfigurationScope configScope)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder.BuildResultMap()
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder.ConfigureSqlMap()
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder.Initialize()
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder.Build(XmlDocument document, DataSource dataSource, Boolean useConfigFileWatcher, Boolean isCallFromDao)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder.Build(XmlDocument document, DataSource dataSource, Boolean useConfigFileWatcher, Boolean isCallFromDao)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder.Build(XmlDocument document, Boolean useConfigFileWatcher)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder.ConfigureAndWatch(String resource, ConfigureHandler configureDelegate)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Configuration.DomSqlMapBuilder.ConfigureAndWatch(ConfigureHandler configureDelegate)
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Mapper.InitMapper()
   at IBatisNet.DataMapper.Mapper.Instance()
   at Net.Autodata.Accessories.Processing.Editor.AccessoryEditor..ctor() in C:\Perforce\Clients\GM\Accessories\Editor\main\Editor.Processing\AccessoryEditor.cs:line 94
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Net.Autodata.Accessories.Processing.Editor.AccessoryEditor..ctor() in C:\Perforce\Clients\GM\Accessories\Editor\main\Editor.Processing\AccessoryEditor.cs:line 98
   at Net.Autodata.Accessories.Editor.AccessoryEditor.LoadEditor() in C:\Perforce\Clients\GM\Accessories\Editor\main\Editor\AccessoryEditor.cs:line 1028

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Project was originally compiled with .Net v1.1  Upgraded IBatis DLL's to 2.0 and now it works fine.